# Mostrar sql gerada pelo JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Há alguma forma de mostrar a SQL gerada pelo JPA/Hibernate sem ser habilitando a propriedade `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>`?

A dificuldade é que preciso monitorar apenas uma query e, se eu ligar o `show_sql` serão logadas todas as queries no console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode habilitar e desabilitar o log do SQL usando o código abaixo

```
Logger sqlLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");
sqlLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

... código ...

sqlLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu ;)